# Why is useState not re-rendering the component in a unit test (Jest, Enzyme)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme

I'm having trouble re-rendering an Enzyme-wrapped component in Jest. It took me a while to narrow down the problem, but it seems to be a problem with `useState` and Enzyme.

I have a component with a button in it. Clicking the button calls a `setState()` function to update component state and re-render. For example:

```
// ...
<Drawer
  classes={{ paper: classes.drawer }}
  anchor="right"
  open={showInfoDrawer}
  variant={mobile() ? 'temporary' : 'persistent'}
  onClose={() => {
    console.log('closing'); // to check onClose simulation works
    setShowInfoDrawer(false);
  }}
  >
  // rest of component...
</Drawer>
// ...
```

In this example, the `setShowInfoDrawer()` is part of a `useState()` hook, passed down as a prop from a parent component.

When I run a test (see example below), the click simulation seems to work, but the component does not re-render.

```
test('should close ActivityInfoDrawer', () => {
  expect(wrappedActivityInfoDrawer.find(Drawer)).toHaveLength(1);
  const wrappedDrawer = wrappedActivityInfoDrawer.find(Drawer);
  // @ts-ignore
  act(() => wrappedDrawer.props().onClose()); // Logs "Clicked..."
  wrappedActivityInfoDrawer.update();
  expect(wrappedActivityInfoDrawer.find(Drawer)).toHaveLength(0); // Fails
  });
```

I did some research and it seems that for a while Enzyme did not support `useState`, but it was address in this [PR](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/pull/2008), which looks like it was released with version 3.11.0, or maybe even 3.10.0 (I'm using 3.11.0, the latest).

What am I doing wrong? Is it because `setShowInfoDrawer()` comes from a parent component? If so, how do I get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. It's pretty obvious in hindsight. I needed to running this test as a test for the **parent component** (ie, the component that opens the drawer and has the `useState()` hook), rather than as a unit test for the Drawer component itself.